# After deserialization cannot cast object

Tags: c#, json

I am serializing and then deserializing a `Dictionary` in Newtonsoft.Json, however the output is not what I expected and is throwing exceptions. Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Task1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dict["int"] = new GenericItem<int> {CreatedAt = DateTime.Now, Object = 111};
            dict["string"] = new GenericItem<string> {CreatedAt = DateTime.Now.Date, Object = "test test"};

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
            var desDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);

            var test = dict["int"] is GenericItem<int>;
            var test2 = dict["int"] as GenericItem<int>;
            var test3 = (GenericItem<int>) dict["int"];

            var desTest = desDict["int"] is GenericItem<int>;
            var desTest2 = desDict["int"] as GenericItem<int>;
            var desTest3 = (GenericItem<int>) desDict["int"];
        }

    }

    public class GenericItem<T>
    {
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public T Object { get; set; }
    }
}
```

First three tests return `True`, Instance of `GenericItem<Int>` and again Instance of `GenericItem<Int>`.

But after deserialization return `false`, `null`, and `InvalidCastException`.

What is the problem? Why after deserealization does it throw `InvalidCastException`?

Comment: Welcome to SO, in the future a bit of background about what you are trying to do will help people answer your question quicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the problem? Why after deserealization does it throw `InvalidCastException`?

The reason of this behaviour is simple - if you check the type of this element with `desDict["int"].GetType()`, you will see that it returns `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` and that's definitely not the type you were expecting.

It is possible to do what you want with usage of `TypeNameHandling` parameter of `JsonSerializerSettings` class, as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390801/1816426). Change this:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
var desDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

to this:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, settings);
var desDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json, settings);
```

Info from reffered answer:

> The TypeNameHandling flag will add a $type property to the JSON, which
>   allows Json.NET to know which concrete type it needs to deserialize
>   the object into. This allows you to deserialize an object while still
>   fulfilling an interface or abstract base class.
>
> The downside, however, is that this is very Json.NET-specific. The
>   $type will be a fully-qualified type, so if you're serializing it with
>   type info,, the deserializer needs to be able to understand it as
>   well.

As an alternative you can loop throught the deserialized dictionary to convert values for each key from `JObject` to desired type:

```
var desDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
var newDict = new Dictionary<string, object>(); //as you can't modify collection in foreach loop and the original dictionary can be out of scope of deserialization code

foreach (var key in desDict.Keys)
{ 
    switch(key)
    {
        case "int":
            newDict[key] = ((JObject)desDict[key]).ToObject<GenericItem<int>>();
            break;
        case "string":
            newDict[key] = ((JObject)desDict[key]).ToObject<GenericItem<string>>();
            break;
    }
}

desDict = newDict;
```

You don't need that manual solution here, but maybe someday this knowledge will be useful. I found info about `JOobject.ToObject()` method in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12208692/1816426). I've checked both methods and both work fine with the code you provided.

Comment: Thank you very much, Konrad! Now everything became clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

You ask it to deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, object>` so it does so. It doesn't store the type information so it builds an object to store the deserialized information in.

I don't think you can get what you want, due to variance issues. You could deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, GenericItem<object>>` but that doesn't seem to be what you wanted. You get a json.net specific object in place of your int or string. You could cast that to what you want.

Comment: It doesn't build a dynamic type, JSON.Net contains its own type called a JObject.

Comment: Thank you. But how to deserialize string as Dictionary<string,  GenericItem<T> > so get my scenario to work?

Comment: @KyleHale whoops my bad being loose on the terminology there.

Answer (score -3):

try :

```
var desDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, GenericItem<object>>>(json);
```

or :

```
var desDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);
```

using dynamic you don't need to cast your object at all, you can just use it's properties