# Reading a JSON file into an object C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON list of players for a game. I need the program to be able to read the JSON file and give me the list of players. Then I can use this list of players to get each player's name and who they are following.

```
{
"Version": "1",
"Users": [
 {
  "UserName": "CoolDude",
  "Following": [ "SniperElitez", "IamAwesome" ]
},
{
  "UserName": "GamerChick",
  "Following": [ "IamAwesome", "NoWayBro", "WowWhoMe", "SniperElitez", "SurfingIsFun", "NowUTry" ]
},
{
  "UserName": "SurfingIsFun",
  "Following": [ "WowWhoMe" ]
},
{
  "UserName": "IamAwesome",
  "Following": [ "GamerChick", "NoWayBro" ]
},
{
  "UserName": "NowUTry",
  "Following": [ "GamerChick", "SniperElitez" ]
},
{
  "UserName": "SniperElitez",
  "Following": [ "SurfingIsFun", "IamAwesome" ]
},
{
  "UserName": "WowWhoMe",
  "Following": [ "NoWayBro", "GamerChick", "SniperElitez" ]
},
{
  "UserName": "NoWayBro",
  "Following": [ "GamerChick", "IamAwesome", "SniperElitez" ]
}
]
}
```

Here is the code I'm trying to use currently
Player Class

```
class Player
{
public string UserName { get; set;}
public List<string> Following { get; set;}
}
```

PlayerList Class

```
class PlayerList
{
    public List<Player> pList { get; set; }

}
```

Main

```
{

string json = File.ReadAllText("friends.json");
// this gives me a playerList object
PlayerList playerList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayerList>(json);

    }
```

Supposedly the PlayerList object is not null but the List is empty. If anyone can tell me how to turn the JSON into the PlayerList object and then from there, get player's variables like UserName, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Well, what's the problem of your code?

Comment: I would recommend trying this site initially to generate your [Json2Csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: I don't quit understand how to access the players in the PlayerList<Player> pList.

Comment: The usernames are hilarious.

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio has a nice feature for parsing XML / JSON... namely, if you copy an XML or a JSON to your clipboard then you can use `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON As Classes` command and have VS automatically generate valid model classes.

In case of your JSON this is the output my VS generated:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public User[] Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string[] Following { get; set; }
}
```

Try that.

Also, you're using `JsonConvert`, which appears to be something by Newtonsoft. I have no idea if it's a good library or not, [but there ARE .NET classes which are capable of deserializing JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp). The linked question offers one method. Another is to use a `DataContractJsonSerializer`, albeit I think the model classes would need to have the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes added to them to work with that.

Comment: Newtonsoft is so good that Microsoft started including it in ASP.Net in preference to their own libraries.

Comment: @MartinBrown In that case don't panic, and carry on. ;) I personally try to avoid using 3rd party libraries if possible, if only because having to attach them to projects to make sure everything compiles can sometimes be a hassle. That said, nugget helps immensely...

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that in the json doc the attribute is called "Users" and in your code you have called it "pList".

There are two solutions to this:

1. Rename PlayerList.pList to PlayerList.Users
2. Add a [JsonProperty](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute on the property to set its name like this:

   class PlayerList
   {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Users")]
       public List pList { get; set; }
   }

Comment: Hooray! when I tested using playerList.Users.Count() it showed up as 8! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by following what was stated in the question at the following link:

[How to deserialize an JObject to .NET object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441466/how-to-deserialize-an-jobject-to-net-object)

Here is my code:

```
        var playerList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        JObject jObject = ((JObject)playerList);
        PlayerList users = jObject.ToObject<PlayerList>();
```

I also renamed the pList to Users on the PlayerList Class.