# How to Serialize a json string with multiple object types?

Tags: c#, .net, json

Let's say I have a json string that looks like this:

```
{
  "customers": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bob"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Mary"
    }
  ],
  "products": [{
      "id": 1,
      "description": "apple",
      "price": 0.50
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "description": "orange",
      "price": 0.75
    }
  ]
}
```

And from that string, I need to get a `List<customer>`:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not seeing in the Newtonsoft docs how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize only one property of a JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701646/deserialize-only-one-property-of-a-json-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Customer
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Customer> customers { get; set; }
    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize your json string into "RootObject"

```
var rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(myJsonString);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [partial JSON fragment deserialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm). All in all you have to load the whole JSON object into a JObject, then select child tokens of that object to convert into the desired type.

Also take a look at [JSON path selection](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) in which you can use token selectors to directly get a part of a JSON.