# How to get string value of key from nested JSON object?

Tags: c#

JSON:

```
{
    event_name: 'request_queue_items',
    event_data: {
        amount: 20
    },
}
```

Event handler:

```
private void OnMessage(string message)
{
    if (!message.Contains("{") || !message.Contains("}"))
    {
        return; // It's not JSON, we don't care...
    }
    
    var jsonObject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message);

    var eventName = jsonObject["event_name"].Value<string>();
    var eventData = jsonObject["event_data"].Value<string>();
    
    Console.WriteLine("RECEIVED: " + eventName);
    Console.WriteLine("WITH DATA: " + eventData);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Error message: `Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken`

Stack trace:

```
12/12/2020 15:19:07 [Error] Application Error System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions.Convert[T,U](T token)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions.Value[T,U](IEnumerable`1 value)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions.Value[U](IEnumerable`1 value)
```

Comment: `event_data` isn't a single value, what are you expecting to see in `eventData` variable?

Comment: Hi @PavelAnikhouski, I am expecting the JSON string of event data, something along the lines of `{amount: 20},`

Comment: It's a deserialization.  Why would you expect a string?

Comment: See my question title, I am asking how to do this.

Comment: Look at this example: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: That seems to be mapping to an object, which isn't what I want.

Comment: Look at your JSON. It describes an object with two properties, `event_name` and `event_data`. The first is a string, the second is an object with on property, `amount`, a number. Create two classes with that structure and deserialize into an instance of the outer class.  Or, deserialize into a `dynamic` and access the amount via `myDynamic.event_data.amount`

Comment: @Flydog57 that isn't what I want, I need to get the string output of the `event_data` property's value, and send it elsewhere. A class doesn't help me here.

Comment: OK, it looks like what you want is `JObject.Parse();`, not `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`.  Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44711550

Comment: Or, you could deserialize things into `class MyClass { public string event_name {get; set;} public dynamic event_data {get; set; } }` and the re-serialize the `event_data` property.  You may want to edit your question to make clear what you wsnt

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following. Use JObject.Parse and use JObject instead of string. You can still get the inner json as a string using .ToString():

```
if (!message.Contains("{") || !message.Contains("}"))
{
    return; // It's not JSON, we don't care...
}

var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(message); // use JObject

var eventName = jsonObject["event_name"].Value<string>();
var eventData = jsonObject["event_data"].Value<JObject>(); //use JObject as it is not a string

Console.WriteLine("RECEIVED: " + eventName);
Console.WriteLine("WITH DATA: " + eventData);
Console.WriteLine();
```

The value of eventData.ToString() will be:

```
event_data: {
    amount: 20
},
```