# How to get key name and its value whereas its value in also in the pair of key value form from json in C#

Tags: c#, json

I am getting response in the format of JObject which is like this.

```
        JObject response = JObject.Parse(account);

       {
        "status": 1,
        "msg": "1 out of 1 Transactions Fetched Successfully",
        "transaction_details": {
           "ae6df74457a7cbf62caf": {
           "mihpayid": "403993715518647003",
           "request_id": "",
           "bank_ref_num": "201833147408756",
           "amt": "88.00",
           "transaction_amount": "88.00",
           "txnid": "ae6df74457a7cbf62caf",
           "additional_charges": "0.00",
           "Settled_At": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
         }
       }
     }
```

Now the "transaction_details" that value ("ae6df74457a7cbf62caf") rapidly change every transaction,So how i get that value and after that how I get "mihpayid" key value in C#.

Comment: You question is not clear, please ask your question as [minimal, complete, verifiable question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have response in the format of string and i convert it into  JObject . Its complete man what do you want please tell me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JObject response = JObject.Parse("{\r\n        \"status\": 1,\r\n        \"msg\": \"1 out of 1 Transactions Fetched Successfully\",\r\n        \"transaction_details\": {\r\n           \"ae6df74457a7cbf62caf\": {\r\n           \"mihpayid\": \"403993715518647003\",\r\n           \"request_id\": \"\",\r\n           \"bank_ref_num\": \"201833147408756\",\r\n           \"amt\": \"88.00\",\r\n           \"transaction_amount\": \"88.00\",\r\n           \"txnid\": \"ae6df74457a7cbf62caf\",\r\n           \"additional_charges\": \"0.00\",\r\n           \"Settled_At\": \"0000-00-00 00:00:00\"\r\n         }\r\n       }\r\n     }");     

        JObject transaction = JObject.Parse(response["transaction_details"].ToString());
        foreach(var token in transaction.Properties()) 
        {
            var rapidlyChangingId = token.Name;
            Console.WriteLine("Rapidly Changing ID: " + rapidlyChangingId);
            Console.WriteLine(transaction[rapidlyChangingId]);
        }
```

> OUTPUT:

`Rapidly Changing ID: ae6df74457a7cbf62caf
{
  "mihpayid": "403993715518647003",
  "request_id": "",
  "bank_ref_num": "201833147408756",
  "amt": "88.00",
  "transaction_amount": "88.00",
  "txnid": "ae6df74457a7cbf62caf",
  "additional_charges": "0.00",
  "Settled_At": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
}`

Comment: Thanks Buddy Its so easy thanks a lot....Really your solution is very very small and Understandable for implement.Really Thanks a lot from core of my Heart.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a class to represent the JSON being returned.
The `transaction_details` part of the object can be represented as a `Dictionary` for example:

```
class Account
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Msg { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, TransactionDetails> transaction_details { get; set; }
}

class TransactionDetails
{
    public string mihpayid { get; set; }
    public string requestid { get; set; }
    public string bank_ref_num { get; set; }
    public string amt { get; set; }
    public string transaction_amount { get; set; }
    public string txnid { get; set; }
    public string additional_charges { get; set; }
    public string Settled_At { get; set; }
}
```

And, instead of using `JObject.Parse(...)` use the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to convert the JSON into your C# class:

```
var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(account);
```

You can now reference all the properties of your JSON using the `myData` object.

You can loop through the `transaction_details` reading each entry.

```
foreach(var item in myData.transaction_details)
{
    var id = item.Key;

    var transaction = item.Value;
    var mihpayid = transaction.mihpayid;
}
```

The values of the variables in the for loop are:

`id` = the unique ID for each transaction i.e. "ae6df74457a7cbf62caf"

`transaction` = a `Transaction` object with all the values from the unique transaction

`mihpayid` = the mihpayid within the unique transaction i.e. "403993715518647003"

Comment: Hi, Buddy thanks a lot i get the value of every key which is in Transaction_Details.But, can u help me to get ( "ae6df74457a7cbf62caf") which is in Transaction_Details other wise all i get.

Comment: var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(response);
            if (myData.transaction_details.Count > 0)
            {
                string TDval = myData.transaction_details.Values.ToString();
            }

Comment: I've updated my answer to include how to read the values from the deserialized JSON. I hope that makes it clearer for you :-)

Comment: Yes Buddy Thanks a Lot for help, your solution is really great.But , little bit its long below your answer which is provided by --  Praneet Nadkar it's too small and also that is working. But really thanks a lot i use your solution in my code .

Answer (score 0):

You can use JObject and convert it to C# object. Something like this:
[How to deserialize an JObject to .NET object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441466/how-to-deserialize-an-jobject-to-net-object)

Comment: Happy to help! :)