# Dynamic Type Conversion in C#

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, type-conversion

I have a lot of lists of different types, and a dictionary that stores for each type the according list. I would like to add an item to the list of its type:

```
    class Demo
    {
        [Serializable] class A{}
        [Serializable] class B{}
        [Serializable] class Z{}

        List<A> a = new List<A>();
        List<B> b = new List<B>();
        List<Z> z = new List<Z>();

        Dictionary<Type, object> dict;

        Demo()
        {
            dict = new Dictionary<Type, object>
            {
                {typeof(List<A>), a},
                {typeof(List<B>), b},
                {typeof(List<Z>), z},
            };
        }

        void Add(dynamic items)
        {
            var type = items.GetType();         
            dynamic list = dict[type];          
            list.AddRange( items );
        }
        
        

        static void Main()
        {
            var demo = new Demo();
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<B>(){new B()});
            var type = typeof(List<B>);

            //compiler has no information of the type of item
            //the type used for deserialization is not known at compile time
            var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, type );
            demo.Add(item);                     
        }
    }
```

This is working, but I wonder whether there is a solution without using the `dynamic` type -
Is there a way to convert the entry in the dictionary to `List<T>`, or do you have another idea how to solve this problem dynamically without `dynamic`?

Please note that I cannot use

```
void Add<T>( T item ) {...}
```

Since the compile-time-type of the item is `object`, for instance from

```
object item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( json , item_type );
```

Comment: Can you post some code that compiles? It's a bit hard to follow what you're doing. For example, what's the underlying type of `items` when passed to `Add()`? You're converting `dict` to the type of `items` and then calling `AddRange()` on it, but `AddRange()` isn't a member of `Dictionary<T>`, so how can you convert `dict` to something that has that member?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deserialize a JObject to .NET object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441466/how-to-deserialize-a-jobject-to-net-object)

Comment: What would you do with the object once it is in the list? If you don't know the type, there isn't much you can do with that anyway, so you may as well just use `object`. If there is specific handling that needs to be done, but when you actually call it you don't need to know what it is, one options is: create a base `abstract` class or interface which supports the functionality you need, then derive from it a generic type `Derived<T> : Base`. Then you can use reflection to create this object, and store it in a `List<Base>`. Now all functionality is available without knowing the actual type.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: sorry, I simplified the actual code too much - my bad

Comment: @funatparties no, since I do not have the type information at compile time

Comment: @Charlieface the list is typed, so the entries in the list behave like normal typed objects

Comment: But what are you going to do with typed objects if you don't know the type at compile time? Do they have a common interface or base class? Or are you using reflection?

Comment: @Charlieface: within the list, the type is known even to the compiler, so once it is in the list, you can do whatever you want. I just try to bypass the dynamic keyword since I like strong typing

Comment: What do you mean "it is known to the compiler"? Even if it is in a `List<A>`, that list is stored in a `Dictionary<Type, object>` so the actual type is not known. Again: what do you propose to *do* with the objects, what functionality do you want to make available? Perhaps they should be in `List<SomeBase>` or `List<SomeInterface>`

Comment: @Charlieface: since the objects in the dictionary (a,b,z) are also available by simply access a,b and z directly, the compiler knows the type -  a,b and z ARE of type List<X> . So the compiler allows a[0].MyMethod() without using dynamic.

Comment: Yes but you would need to cast the list itself, as it is stored in a `Dictionary<Type, object>`. You're still not telling us what you hope to *do* with these objects. Please give an actual example of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: the objects in the lists are data upserted from different sources and used from time to time for calculations, where I have to return somthing like a.Where( x => x.timestamp > threshold ).
I do not need to cast the lists, since they are not only in the dict but also in the class. so I can access it by demo.a, demo.b etc.

Answer (score 0):

use reflection:

```
void Add(object items)
{
    var type = items.GetType();
    var method = type.GetMethod("AddRange");
    var list = dict[type];                                              
    var ret = method.Invoke(list, new object[]{items} );
}
```

Comment: this is a correct solution since it solves the problem without using `dynamic`.  However, using a string with the name of the method looks even worse than `dynamic`. I keep looking for a more elegant solution -